# Why in "Fukkatsu no F" the words order are inverted?

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-の, word-order

Phrases like "ore no shugyō", "my training" (training of me) , the person comes first and the noun second, but in phrases like "Fukkatsu no F" or "Fukushū no Gōruden Furīza" the order is inverted.

Comment: I'd like to know what "Fukkatsu no F" is inverted compared to.

Comment: @Pablo, if you could edit your question a bit to expand, we might be able to give you a better answer.  As broccoli forest also mentioned, we're not sure what "inversion" you're talking about.  Could you give some examples of this inversion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you suggested, "Fの復活" would be far more straightforward and simply means "The Return of F", but "復活のF" is not a typo, of course. In "復活のF", the main noun is "F", and 復活の is a phrase that modifies "F". Think of it as something like "F, The Resurrected" or "Returning F".

Basically you can re-analyze this title as "復活するF" or "復活したF", as if the modifying part were a normal suru-verb. This is probably not a part of the "standard" Japanese grammar, but you may occasionally find this pattern in book or movie titles because it's shorter and somehow looks cooler due to its nonstandard appearance. As chocolate said, 進撃の巨人 (lit. "Advancing Giants") is another good recent example of this.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems a bit confused, as nothing looks inverted to me.

A simple way of understanding how の works, for folks coming from English, is to view the の as the **'s** in English -- it's basically a possessive.  So *"John​**'s** apple"* in Japanese becomes ジョンさん**の**リンゴ in Japanese.

In your last two sample phrases, 復活{ふっかつ}**の**F (*"Fukkatsu **no** F"*) would be *"fukkatsu​**'s** F"*, and 復讐{ふくしゅう}**の**ゴールデンフリーザ (*"Fukushū **no** Gōruden Furīza"*) would be *"Revenge​**'s** Golden Freezer"*.

It's only if you rework the English to use *"of"* instead of the possessive **'s** that the word order changes.

(All that being said, translating **anything** from one language to another one will inevitably result in a change in the order of ideas.  This is simply because different languages are **different**.)

Comment: I think his question relates to the fact that, for example, ジョンのリンゴ and 復讐のジョン both essentially translate in English respectively to, 'John's apple' and 'John's revenge',  yet the order of the possession is changed for some reason in Japanese.

Comment: @ciaran yes, that's my question

Comment: _"John's revenge"_ would be ジョンの復讐 -- same order as in English.  復讐のジョン does not parse out to _"John's revenge"_, but rather the other way around: _"revenge's John"_ in a literal translation, with the meaning more like _"John as a thing belonging to or of revenge (possibly as the instrument of revenge)"_.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Well I see your point, and I do think it answers the question, but how would you translate it? "Revenge's John" might be literal, but it doesn't really make sense in English.

Comment: @Ciaran, yes, the literal translation doesn't quite make sense.  This gets into the weeds a bit in terms of how different constructions require different translation approaches.  Sometimes a simple two- or three-word phrase in Language A requires a longer and more convoluted expression in Language B to get the idea across, or a different grammatical approach.  For 復讐のジョン: Is this a title?  Is this a phrase in a longer text?  Etc.  As a title, I might render this as _Vengeful John_ or _Revenging John_, depending on the content of the work.

Comment: Downvoter: Please comment.  This website is intended as a resource, and posts are meant to be informative.  If there's something you disagree with, or think could be better stated, **please comment** so that the posts (and the site as a whole) may be improved.

Comment: `復讐のジョン As a title, I might render this as Vengeful John or Revenging John` -> そうですね！「復讐するジョン」みたいなイメージですね。ちょっと、「進撃の巨人」、みたいな感じで・・・。DVに関しては：分かりませんけど、コメントに書かれている、「復讐の～～」の具体的な意味・解釈を、回答にも付け加えてみてはいかがでしょう？

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but doesn't  復活のF mean "the F of Fukkatsu', or "F for Fukkatsu" - i.e. "R for Revival"? If so,  復讐の F would be "V for Vengeance".